# ERROR: syntax error at or near "if" Position: 1 - Redshift SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Below is my sql query:

```
IF EXISTS(select 1 from
          #temp tmp
          join dbo.mytable_test t
          on t.logonname = tmp.logonname
          where (t.admincode <> tmp.admincode
          or t.lastname <> tmp.lastname
          or t.firstname <> tmp.firstname)
BEGIN
  insert into dbo.mytable_hist
  select tmp.admincode,
         tmp.lastname,
         tmp.firstname,
         tmp.middlename,
         tmp.email,
         tmp.loaddate
  from dbo.mytable_test t
  join #temp tmp on t.logonname = tmp.logonname
  where (t.admincode <> tmp.admincode
  or t.lastname <> tmp.lastname
  or t.firstname <> tmp.firstname)

  delete from #temp tmp 
  join dbo.mytable_test t on t.logonname = tmp.logonname
  where (t.admincode <> tmp.admincode
  or t.lastname <> tmp.lastname
  or t.firstname <> tmp.firstname)
END
commit
```

This query checks for every row in the temp table to see if anything is different. If they are, then the row will be pushed to _hist table and then deleted from old table.

I run this sql query in redshift and constantly see the below error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "IF"
  Position: 875

IF EXISTS(select 1 from
```

On the logical perspective things look correct. I'm unsure why this error is cause. Any idea how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

This is an error because there is no Redshift command "IF".  It looks like you may be trying to define a stored procedure without actually defining the procedure.  "If" statements can exist inside a stored procedure.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_PROCEDURE.html

Comment: ok i'll try adding a create proc statement